# How to add a custom source file dependency in cmake that is compiled into the target the first time around

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies

I have the following CMakefile.txt snippet that is supposed to generate defaultIdentity.c so that it is built for foo.so library target. What actually happens, is that initially defaultIdentity.c is created, but not compiled into foo.so.
On subsequent runs it is compiled into foo.so probably because it already exists.
I assume that this is some sort of generation time, build time issue, but am completely stumped on how to make this actually work.
Since i failed to find cmake documentation that elaborates on this, i sort of pieced this together out various snippets found on the web.

```
set(CERTFILE /path/to/certfile)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT defaultIdentity.c
        COMMAND cat ${CERTFILE} > defaultId
        COMMAND xxd -i defaultId > defaultIdentity.c
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${CERTFILE})

add_custom_target(defaultIdentity DEPENDS defaultIdentity.c)

file(GLOB TKNAME_SOURCES *.[hc] ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/defaultIdentity.c)

add_library(${TKNAME} SHARED ${TKNAME_SOURCES})

add_dependencies(${TKNAME} defaultIdentity)
```

Could anybody elaborate on how to actually make this work?

Comment: `add_custom_command` doesn't run the command  immediately but postpones it to the **build** step. In opposite, `file(GLOB)` searches files immediately, at **configuration** stage. So, the first time `cmake` is run, there is no `defaultIdentity.c` in the build directory, and `file(GLOB)` doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm sure there's a way to do this, but it seems neither i, nor someone else found a way to do this.

Since my source is rather static, i just created the file manually and added it to my sources.
Case closed.